# Statistics or machine learning tools for inductive transfer

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, statistical-significance, iid

Transfer learning, inductive transfer and multitask learning are becoming more popular nowadays.

From my understanding, some of these methods use iid units/subjects and model them simultaneously in hope to learn from their commonalities.

An example of a famous inductive process that does that is the Gaussian process (GP) for computer experiments. The GP takes iid points in the space and induces a correlation between through assuming these points as random variables from a common multivariate distribution.

This inductive transfer of iid points is just a mathematical trick that learns the commonalities between units.

What are other famous statistics and machine learning tools that also use iid units and provide a shared representation to learn from their commonalities? In other words what are common inductive processes in machine learning and statistics.